# Return Class in Java with Class as parameter

Tags: java, class, parameters, return

I need to write a method that compares an integer variable of two classes and returns the one with a higher value, but I don't know how to return the class using the method. Example:

```
public Class returnClass (Class c) {

   if (value < c.getValue())

      return c;

   else

     return this.class;

}
```

How would the right way of doing this be?

Comment: What is the comparable "value" of an instance?

Comment: Oops, made a mess rewriting that one! It compares two integer variables!

Comment: Assuming `Class` is just an example here, change `return this.class;` to `return this;`

Comment: You got the answer of your question?

Answer (score 0):

From your else block just use `return this.getClass()`

In Java, `this` basically means you current object and you can call all method present in `Object` class, so you can call `getClass` method from it.

As an aside,

- If from your method you were returning `Object` then you could have done `return this;`, but since you are returning `Class` so you cannot return `this` (*mentioning this point because few folks are suggesting to return `this`*)
- You should careful between usage of `java.lang.Class` and your own `Class` class, generally **it is not advisable** to use same class names as Java API, so **you must consider** updating your `Class` class name to something else.

Comment: Here is the [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) Javadoc. There is no `getValue()`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, because apparently it is his user defined class, see my latest update where I am recommending him not to use confusing class names.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way would be `return this;`
It returns the current object instance.